# Ubuntu - VMM Failing to make .qcow2 images larger than 5 GiB

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm trying to get *Virtual Machine Manager* to run on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu. Thus far, I haven't encountered many issues, but there is one issue that I can't overcome:

When I try to create a Storage Volume for a new QEMU/KVM guest, it errors out if the volume is supposed to be larger than 5 GiB. It will start the process of creating the disk image, but then will throw an error at ~3.6 GB

This is the error message:

```
Error creating vol: Couldn't create storage volume 'cryslinux.qcow2': 'internal error: Child process (/user/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,compat=1.1,lazy_refcounts\

'/media/<username>/SD CARD/kvm/cryslinux.qcow2' 11534336K) unexpected exit status 1: qemu-img: Failed to flush the refcount block cache: File too large\

qemu-img: /media/<username>/SD CARD/kvm/ cryslinux.qcow2: The image size is too large for file format 'qcow2' (try using a larger cluster size)'
```

Edit: I tried switching it to use .raw volumes instead, but it gives me a different error:

```
Operation not permitted
```

I only have .qcow2 and .raw as volume options

Comment: What is the filesystem the resulting qcow2 image is being saved on (`df -Th "/media/<username>/SD CARD/kvm/"` should display the type)?  Some filesystems have limitations that they cannot support files larger than 4gb which seems to be the limit you are hitting.

Comment: @GracefulRestart It's not just an issue with the SD card. I've tried it on internal storage, this SD Card, and other storage. Everything had a different file system

Comment: I was not asking about the SD card, I am asking about which filesystem the SD card was formatted with.  That information can be found by running the command in my previous comment.  I am interested in what the `type` of your filesystem is as some filesystems have limitations on the size of individual files.

Comment: @GracefulRestart That particular SD card is a 2-partition drive. The partition I was using was NTFS